# Footer TCPD cannot execute

Tags: php, pdf, footer, tcpdf

I have script

```
class MYPDF extends TCPDF {
   public function Header(){
   //die('aaa');
   }

   public function Footer() {
    die('aaa');
    $this->SetY(-5);
    // Set font
    //$this->SetFont('helvetica', 'I', 8);
    // Page number
    $html='aaa';
    $pdf->writeHTMLCell(0, 0, '', '', $html, 0, 0, false, "L", true);
    //$this->Cell(0, 10, 'Page '.$this->getAliasNumPage().'/'.$this->getAliasNbPages(), 0, false, 'C', 0, '', 0, false, 'T', 'M');
    } 
}
$pdf = new MYPDF();
....
```

But footer function cannot execute. But if i uncommet die('aaa') in header function it's works. But in footer function die('aaa') cannot execute. Why?

Comment: ok .. do one thing ... try to change the name of your FOOTER function to something like Footer_mypdf and then try.

Comment: you can also try to put your FOOTER function above your HEADER function like someone did here [custom PHP tcpdf footer with top and bottom border](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28275193/custom-php-tcpdf-footer-with-top-and-bottom-border)

Comment: so you tried both the things above .. correct ?

Comment: if yes then now do one thing , instead of this **class MYPDF extends TCPDF {** try this **class MYPDF {** just exclude extending it into your class and then see what happens.

Comment: you also did not show how you are calling your FOOTER .. if you can show it like this are you doing **$pdf->Footer();** ?

Comment: OK solved. Thanks ....

Comment: what was an issue btw ?