# php class tcpdf. delete bottom line, above page numder

Tags: php, tcpdf

I use class **tcpdf** for creating a **pdf** document.

Then I have an method `$pdf->SetFooterMargin(15);`, that inserts number page and black line above number.

I'd like to delete this line. How can I do this.

Comment: Can you show more code ?

Comment: Yes. What would you like to see? There are many string with code. I made class object $pdf and used this method. When I commented this line, line and numder  page disappeared from my document. It's not my goal.

Comment: If the answer below is not good yes please.

Comment: this code created PDF doc

$pdf = new DeltaPDF(PDF_PAGE_ORIENTATION, PDF_UNIT, PDF_PAGE_FORMAT, true, 'UTF-8', false);
$pdf->SetCreator(PDF_CREATOR);

$articleName = $data['name_' . LANGUAGE_CURRENT];

// set document info
$pdf->SetAuthor('TravelBlog');
$pdf->SetTitle($articleName);
$pdf->SetSubject($articleName);
$pdf->SetKeywords('TravelBlog');

// set margins
$pdf->SetMargins(15, 45, 15, 15);
$pdf->SetFooterMargin(15);

Comment: Have you tried the code in the example ?

Comment: Yes, I inserted this function and it worked. But numder put on the top on page. And numder is only on empty page whithout text.

Comment: Maybe now you will show us your source.

Comment: $pdf = new DeltaPDF(PDF_PAGE_ORIENTATION, PDF_UNIT, PDF_PAGE_FORMAT, true, 'UTF-8', false);
$pdf->SetCreator(PDF_CREATOR);

$articleName = $data['name_' . LANGUAGE_CURRENT];

// set document info
$pdf->SetAuthor('TravelBlog');
$pdf->SetTitle($articleName);
$pdf->SetSubject($articleName);
$pdf->SetKeywords('TravelBlog');

// set margins
$pdf->SetMargins(15, 45, 15, 15);
//$pdf->SetFooterMargin(15);
$pdf->Footer();
// set font
$pdf->setFontSubsetting(true);
$pdf->SetFont('DejaVuSans', '', 9);

// add a page
$pdf->AddPage();

Comment: public function Footer() {
        // Position at 15 mm from bottom
        $this->SetY(-17);
        // Set font
        $this->SetFont('helvetica', 'I', 10);
        // Page number
        $this->Cell(0, 10, 'Page '.$this->getAliasNumPage().'/'.$this->getAliasNbPages(), 0, false, 'R', 0, '', 0, false, 'T', 'M');
    }
}

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at this [example](https://tcpdf.org/examples/example_003/). There is no line above page numbers and this is the function for the footer

```
public function Footer() {
    // Position at 15 mm from bottom
    $this->SetY(-15);
    // Set font
    $this->SetFont('helvetica', 'I', 8);
    // Page number
    $this->Cell(0, 10, 'Page '.$this->getAliasNumPage().'/'.$this->getAliasNbPages(), 0, false, 'C', 0, '', 0, false, 'T', 'M');
}
```

Edit: just make it like this

```
public function Footer() {
    // Position at 15 mm from bottom
    $this->SetY(-15);
    // Set font
    $this->SetFont('helvetica', 'I', 8);
    // Page number
    $this->Cell(0, 10, 'Page '.$this->getAliasNumPage().'/'.$this->getAliasNbPages(), 0, false, 'C', 0, '', 0, false, 'T', 'M');
} 
$pdf = new DeltaPD ....
...
...
```

Comment: I used method $pdf->Footer(). Maybe I didn't understand all code, but it didn't work. This method without arguments.

Comment: Put the function Footer inside the class.

Comment: I did it.  But numder put on the top on page. And numder is only on empty page whithout text.

Comment: Why this function created empty first page?

Comment: Please edit you question and put it there. It will be more readable and more people can see it and eventually helping.

Comment: Thanks, it worked. My mistake. I put this method in my class and call it on page with my object. When I deleted call this function - it was good... Thanks...

Comment: And last, please. How can I make numder more near to right side

$this->Cell(0, 10, ''.$this->getAliasNumPage().'/'.$this->getAliasNbPages(), 0, false, 'R', 0, '', 0, false, 'T', 'M');

Comment: @sergey, please check this SO thread. It should help you: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28275193/custom-php-tcpdf-footer-with-top-and-bottom-border

Comment: Thx for the nice answer and supporting your fellow dev :p

Comment: Thanks @Drew .. I'm trying :)